# Обновление виджетов при переключении нас другие Screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Как обновлять виджеты при переключении на другой Screen в ScreenManager?

Я создал функцию, которая каждые полсекунды проверяет глобальную переменную, и при переключении на другой экран, при условии, что переменная изменилась, и происходит обновление.

Есть понимание, что это не совсем правильно. Возможно, что должно такое действие происходить через метод `manager.some_method()` или же через `property`. Должен изменяться список из кнопок при переключении на данный экран, где должна изменяться просто надпись на кнопках, к примеру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании класса экрана и при наследовании от класса Screen нужно указать `self.on_enter=self.name_function` - без скобок в конце и обязательно с `self`'ами.
(Вначале пробовал писать без `self` и ничего не происходило).